# Torque error copying output files even though the destination exists

Tags: nfs, pbs, torque

Most of the time our torque jobs run fine. Every now and then we get emails saying:

```
PBS Job Id: 1234.master.example.com
Job Name:   myjob
Exec host:  worker1.example.com/38
An error has occurred processing your job, see below.
request to copy stageout files failed on node
'worker1.example.com/38' for job
1234.master.example.com

Unable to copy file
/var/spool/torque/spool/1234.master.example.com.OU to
/home/someuser/myjob.log,
error 1
*** error from copy
/bin/cp: cannot stat
`/var/spool/torque/spool/1234.master.example.com.OU': No
such file or directory
*** end error output
```

Now, we have `usecp` set up correctly, `/home` is mounted on every machine. And most of the time everything works fine, log files are copied to their destination and there are no error emails. It's only intermittently that we get the error emails. Now the weird thing is, even when we get these error emails, the log files actually exist at the destination we expected them at (eg: `/home/someuser/myjob.log`). It looks like the log files were copied successfully, except for the email.

What I think may be happening is something like:

1. The job finishes successfully and copies the log files from /var/spool to the destination on the shared NFS directory successfully.
2. The log files on the execution host under /var/spool are deleted.
3. The mom is instructed to run the job exit procedure again (maybe there was a breakdown in communication between the mom and the server and the server didn't think the job exited yet).
4. The mom tries to copy the log files from /var/spool to the destination on NFS again and fails because they were already deleted in step 2 after the successful copy.

But it's hard to debug because it only happens intermittently.

Comment: What is the load on your NFS server when this happens? High load may be causing something to time out but does eventually finish.

Comment: I think load might be fairly high, though not incredibly high. Also we don't get any NFS errors anywhere else. And if there was an NFS timeout error, the error from torque would probably mention an error on write, not an error with not being able to stat the source file in /var/spool.

Comment: OK. It was one thought I had to explain an intermittent issue like this. Do you have epilogue scripts to clean up your environment(kill leftover processes and delete files) after a job?

Comment: No epilogue scripts defined at the moms nor job specific epilogue scripts.

Comment: I see the email mentions stageout. Are you using stagein/stageout with the -W flag?

Comment: No these jobs aren't using stageout (though we might want to use stagein/stageout in the future). I think torque just uses the same technique to copy stderr/stdout back to the execution host as it does for stageout files.

Comment: For now, I'm out of ideas as to what is wrong. If this continues to be an issue you could set Torque to write the file directly to NFS. Good luck with this.

Comment: That's actually what we ended up doing. I don't love using that option as it just kind of avoids what is probably still a problem between the moms and the server and/or scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

We have experienced the same, but it happened more regularly at times (like every 15 minutes or so). A restart of the `pbs_server` service has helped (in the short term) though.